# Online resize virtual machine disks on Xenserver or Xen

Tags: resize, disk, xen

I try to increase vitrual disk on running Xen VM.

I use command `xe vdi-resize uuid=a68471c4-e4f6-4e8f-9cde-74cba33d67d1 disk-size=13GiB online=true`

where `a68471c4-e4f6-4e8f-9cde-74cba33d67d1` is uuid of my xen guest VM.

I try to increase disk size on running VM, but I have a error:

The SR backend does not support the operation (check the SR's allowed operations)
sr: e062ce43-056b-1044-02af-00fd6c8dc028 (iSCSI virtual disk storage)

I use iSCSI virtual disk storage

What I do wrong?

I use latest Xenserver version/

Has the Xenserver online disk resize feature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to give the uuid of the VM, you should be using the uuid of the disk you're trying to resize...

```
xe vm-disk-list vm="myVM"

Disk 0 VBD:
uuid ( RO)             : 0b1c2c6a-280b-68fd-dd8d-fb1c42f2ab80
    vm-name-label ( RO): myVM
       userdevice ( RW): 0


Disk 0 VDI:
uuid ( RO)             : 7b8df1e0-2f0c-4176-44a7-6fa94c42c4fa
       name-label ( RW): myVM 0
    sr-name-label ( RO): Netapp
     virtual-size ( RO): 32212254720
```

7b8df1e0-2f0c-4176-44a7-6fa94c42c4fa is the uuid you need to give to the vdi-resize command.

Comment: Hello! 

Thank you for your answer. 

I run command xe vm-disk-list vm="vm1" and get uuid of my VM virtual disk.

But when I try to run command xe vdi-resize uuid=de13a9eb-32a9-4674-9b0c-b9fa2b04f701 disk-size=10GiB online=true

I get this error:

The SR backend does not support the operation (check the SR's allowed operations)

What I do wrong? Xen server can't resize disk on running VM?

Comment: If it does not accept your command with online=true, than the client VM does not support online resizes.

Answer (score 0):

The command "xe vdi-resize online=true uuid=VDI" is valid in the XenAPI but not documented on the [admin guide](https://docs.citrix.com/content/dam/docs/en-us/xenserver/current-release/downloads/xenserver-administrators-guide.pdf#[%7B%22num%22%3A2428%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C242.617%2Cnull]).

But the API guide mentions the command [resize_online](https://docs.citrix.com/content/dam/docs/en-us/xenserver/current-release/downloads/xenserver-management-api-guide.pdf#[%7B%22num%22%3A8039%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C651.887%2Cnull]).

I tested on SR type shared lvm and local ext and got the SR_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED error on both.
It seems that the SR need the param VDI.resize_online and that currently no SR implements that.

The following [link](http://xs-devel.xenserver.narkive.com/a0HjtKFo/online-vdi-resize-on-ext3#post3) mentions that this param was removed in 2011 because of reliability issues.

So as it seems, online resizing is currently not supported for all SR types.

cf. [source](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/393302-xenserver-%E2%80%9Cxe-vdi-resize-onlinetrue%E2%80%9D-is-there-a-case-where-it-works/?source=email)